# How to measure travel time of a socket message?

Tags: c++, sockets, optimization, network-programming

I have client and server applications on 2 different servers in an intranet. How can I measure the time taken for a message to be sent from server to client? (I cannot depend on machine timestamps, since they might be off)

Answer (score 2):

Ping the server from the client, divide the time reported by two. That's a pretty good, though slightly optimistic estimate of practical latency. (Ping uses the ICMP protocol; you'll get different measurements with a TCP application since TCP needs to [set up a connection](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) first.)

If you want to do this in a C++ application, your best option may be to call the `ping` command and parse its output. Esp. on Unix, where you commonly need `root` privileges to send ICMP packets.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot rely on synchronized clock, the only way is to have a message going there and back, like a ping does. If you want to know how long only trip there (or a trip back) takes, you can divide by two.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ping`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping) to get an approximate measure of the packet round-trip time from the client to the server and back.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to an accurate time source on each machine you can either use that directly for time stamps, or use it to calculate the difference between the machines' clocks. What accurate time source? GPS. Here's the first link to a product that Google supplies: [(link)](http://www.beaglesoft.com/stsyhome.htm).